# Is there a loss function when estimating a model using MCMC?

Tags: time-series, bayesian, forecasting, markov-chain-montecarlo, nonparametric

I am trying to understand how fitting a model using MCMC works. Is there a loss function that is optimized?

Or is it simply a case of more draws from the distribution amount to a more complete description of the posterior and therefore more accurate parameters?

In particular I am referring to how a BSTS time series model is fitted using MCMC draws as described in Scott and Varian "Predicting the Present with Bayesian Structural Time Series", 2013.

In that paper a state space model of a time series is described:

$y_t = Z_t^T \alpha_t + \epsilon_t $.

$\alpha_{t+1} = T_t \alpha_t + R_t\eta_t$

Let

$\theta = (Z, T, R, \epsilon, \eta)$

and

$\textbf{y} = y_1,....y_n$ their time series data.

They then use MCMC to simulate the posterior distribution of the parameters of the model given their data $p(\theta|\textbf{y})$ - and presumably (they don't actually states this, I am assuming) they select $\theta$ that maximizes $p(\theta|\textbf{y})$.

In R the BSTS model takes a number of MCMC draws as an input parameter - and I am trying to figure how to choose that number.

If it is the second case (more draws = better simulation of the distribution), how do we decided the number of iterations and how do we avoid overfitting?

Comment: Your question is too broad; MCMC may be used in various ways (for example, it encompasses optimization via simulated annealing). Are you talking about fitting a Bayesian model? Please give more context.

Comment: You are confusing inference (estimation) and simulation (MCMC), precision in the estimation and precision of the Monte Carlo approximation.

Comment: @Glen_b I've added details.

Comment: @Xi'an I'm not talking about inference - the paper I'm reading specifically states that they are using MCMC simulation to train their model.

Comment: Your question has reopened. @Xi'an's comment still stands. 'Train the model' is estimation (it certainly will be in this instance).

Comment: @Glen_b "The model is fit using an MCMC algorithm" are the original authors words not mine.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how that changes the point being made about confusing precision in the estimation and precision of the Monte Carlo approximation.

Comment: This is clearer but there is no such thing as overfitting associated with an MCMC chain. The more the better.

Comment: @Alex Bayesian estimation has notable links to loss functions. You should learn *how* $\hat{\theta}$ is taken from $p(\theta|y)$. In minimax theory, different estimators optimize different losses: the median with L1 loss, the mean with L2 loss and the mode with Linf loss: all of these are used in practice. The use of MCMC is just to numerically calculate the shape of $p(\theta|y)$: we can assume it has no bearing on the actual "loss" function that is minimized by the estimator $\hat{\theta} = f(p(\theta|y))$.

Comment: @AdamO - Ok - but the MCMC must be converging towards something? Otherwise why do specify a number of iterations?

Comment: @Alex No MCMC is not converging to anything. It is sampling from $p(\theta|y)$. Our estimate of $\widehat{p(\theta|y)}$ gets better with more samples, so there is a functional convergence. This forms the shape of the posterior. That shape in fact tells us very little. To report something useful, we reduce this shape into a statistic. What I am saying is only that that statistic has some link with a loss function. In this way, the relation between MCMC and loss-functions is just incidental. We could still do the same thing when $p(\theta|y)$ has a closed form solution.

Answer (score 2):

For Bayesian estimation, the point of MCMC is only to simulate data from--and thereby obtain an estimate of--the posterior. In general, MCMC (Markov Chain Monte Carlo) only refers to generating realizations or [simulating data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain_Monte_Carlo) from a probability model. This is necessary for Bayesian analyses where the posterior if often not solvable in a closed form. [Gibbs Sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_sampling) is perhaps the most popular technique for obtaining a posterior and it happens to be MCMC, but there are [other approaches](http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~rjs57/RSS/0708/Rue08.pdf).

These simulation methods are imprecise, but we do not call this loss (in the same way that a blurry image could be called "lossy"). We call this precision. Increasing the number of iterations of Gibbs sampling will generally increase the precision with which the density of the posterior can be estimated. The lack of precision is called MCMC error.

Rather, loss is a general concept of [Bayesian estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes_estimator). In practice, we make no distinction between posteriors which are estimated from MCMC or posteriors which are known in exact form when we discuss the loss of estimators. The risk (expected loss) is calculated the same way. Optimal Bayes estimators minimize risk.